# Apply a lambda function to iterate over two columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda

I have a pandas df:

```
pd.DataFrame({'61 - 90': [np.NaN, 14, np.NaN, 9, 34, np.NaN],
         '91 and over': [np.NaN, 10, np.NaN, 1, np.NaN, 9]})
```

I am trying to apply a lambda function that returns False if BOTH columns for a record == np.NaN.  My attempt at solving this:

```
df['not_na'] = df[['61 - 90', '91 and over']].apply(lambda x: False if pd.isna(x) else True)
```

The error message I receive:

> ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 61 - 90')

Comment: `>>> df.isna().all(axis=1)`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you do:

```
df['not_na'] = df[['61 - 90', '91 and over']].notnull().any(axis=1)
```

Comment: Awesome this works! I didn't know about the .notnull() method! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To do this using a lambda function over a data frame For elementwise operations. we need to use applymap

```
df[['61 - 90', '91 and over']].applymap(lambda x: False if pd.isna(x) else True)
```

the documentation for applymap fuction is availablein the link below
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html